# rendering a rigged 2D character

Tags: rendering, animation, rigging, image

I'm using blender to create a 2-D animation. I have made a character by importing .pngs of the characters body parts, placing them together and applying a rig (I used this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=htFYQcvHXUs). But when I go to render the animation, the character's limbs are in each others way; the head overlaps a bit of the chest and some of his shoulder and his arms when when he raises them above his head.

[image]

[image]

Anyone know what I did wrong/how I can fix this?

Comment: How do you want it to work? The head to be behind everything? Also, it looks like the arm might be using *Mask transparency* in the second screenshot. If that's not what you want, try setting it to *Z transparency* instead.

Comment: Check if your animation makes any transformations on the depth axis. This will make things overlap and cause some transparency problems. Also make sure that all the correct transparency settings are on. It can also be really useful to have a example .blend file. Without it, we have to guess what your problem is and we can't be as useful.

Answer (score 3):

While you are working with 2D, don't forget that the Z axis still exists! If you're doing 2D you should be using an orthographic camera, so further elements won't appear farther. The Z axis essentially becomes the sorting order:

[image: Z axis]

[image: Rendered]

The reason your arm is cutting through the head is because you have the transparency set to **Mask** instead of **Z Transparency**. Just go through and make sure everything is on Z Transparency, and you should be good.

[image: Mask vs. Z Transparency]

Comment: I started this thread by stating that I'm somewhat new to blender, but it appears to have been edited out. As such, I probably don't know what you're talking about and may have to ask for more info, but I'll see what I can do. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @SamSpielberg I have to say, though the user did fix a few grammar errors, they removed a significant amount of information from your post. That is inappropriate. The title was arguably better before, because your question is about the rendering, not the rigging.

Comment: Yeah, that was weird. Anyway, your suggestion worked. Everything is functioning as planned. Appreciate it!

Comment: @SamSpielberg Great! Glad I could help! Since it solved your problem, I'd appreciate it if you clicked the checkmark outline to the left of my answer to mark it as the accepted one :)